# Strange Flagolett notation in Küchler op.12

Tags: violin

I am practicing Ferdinand Küchler's Concertino op. 12, and the second movement (Andante cantabile) ends like this (see image). I know the natural flagolett (04) which brings an octave of the string, but how do I finger this? How do I finger the d and octave d at the same time (second last bar) and how do I finger the last bar? Please tell me string and finger resp.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're not meant to play two pitches simultaneously. The music is showing both the pitches that are meant to be heard (the top notes) and the way of producing them via harmonics (the bottom notes). The "ad lib." means that, *if you want*, you can play them as harmonics; if not, you would just play the D and G as normal (presumably in 3rd position, using 1st and 4th fingers on A). Since there are many other harmonics sprinkled throughout the Concertino, this option is probably provided not so much to be "easier," as simply in case the performer wants the more "solid" sound of a non-harmonic note.

If you want to play the harmonics, the suggested fingering assumes that you remain in third position, as indicated in the previous measures, and use 2 and 1 on G string. You could also 1st or 2nd position should you want to (though 3rd is probably best).

Comment: Thanks, Andy, but what fingers do I use? I edited my question, maybe it had not been clear

Comment: @Fuzzy Actually, as I look at the context, I'm sure it's the second option. Let me edit my answer...